# Have I performed the following definite integral correctly?

Tags: calculus, integration

I suppose it's two questions I have really. Firstly, whether or not I evaluated the following integral correctly by partial fractions, and secondly if I did, then if part of the answer for a definite integral is undefined, is the whole thing undefined? My guess is that it's not and it just depends on your interpretation of what the integration actually means in a specific application..

$$\int_{0}^{4}\frac{x - 1}{x^2 - 4x -5}$$
$$\frac{x - 1}{x^2 - 4x -5} = \frac{A}{x - 5} + \frac{B}{x + 1}$$
$$x - 1 = A(x + 1) + B(x - 5)$$
$$x = -1 : -2 = -6B,\, B = \frac13$$
$$x = 5 : 4 = 6A,\, A = \frac23$$

$$\int_{0}^{4}\frac{2}{3x - 15}+\frac{1}{3x + 3}$$

$$\frac23\ln(3x - 15) + \frac13\ln(3x + 3)\Big|_0^4$$

$$\frac23\ln(-3) + \frac13\ln(15) - \frac23\ln(15) - \frac13\ln(3)$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might attract more respondents and proofreaders if you type up your work. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @probablyme Thanks I'll begin familiarizing myself with typing up math.

Comment: @Bacon Well so far as I can see substituting $x = 5$ gives the same answer for $A$ that I got? i.e. $4 = 6A$ which implies $A = \frac{2}{3}$ and well yes the limits of integration of 0 to 4 are what are given in my book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singularities of the function are at $x=-1$ and $x=5$, outside the integration range, so there's nothing undefined.

$$\int_{0}^{4}\frac{x - 1}{x^2 - 4x -5}=\frac23\int_{0}^{4}\frac{dx}{x-5}+\frac13\int_{0}^{4}\frac{dx}{x+1}=\left.\frac23\ln(|x-5|)\right|_0^4+\left.\frac13\ln(|x+1|)\right|_0^4\\
=-\frac{\ln(5)}3.$$

---

Note that

$$x>a\implies\int\frac{dx}{x-a}=\ln(x-a),\\
x<a\implies\int\frac{dx}{x-a}=\int\frac{-dx}{a-x}=\ln(a-x).$$

This is summarized by

$$\int\frac{dx}{x-a}=\ln(|x-a|)$$ provided that the integration interval doesn't straddle $a$, otherwise the integral is undefined because of the singularity (by the way, the two signs cannot hold simultaneously).

Comment: So when you integrate $\frac1x$ should the antiderivative always be $ln(|x|)$ with an absolute value?

Comment: @fella27: indeed. Without it, you haven't solved the integral in the negatives. And unless you use the theory of improper integrals, the domain of integration cannot straddle $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks, the note you appended to your answer was helpful.